# call jquery event after getting the current page id from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My knowledge in Javascript is not that good and I used a sample code I got from the web and need help in that.

I have a jquery multi level menu and I have a problem to open one section of the menu after getting the current viewed page id from the php (wordpress).

I'm using wordpress custom post type (taxonomy) to create category and pages, below is my code.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var menu_ul = $('.aside-menu > li > ul'),
        menu_a  = $('.aside-menu > li > a');

    menu_ul.hide();

    menu_a.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            menu_a.removeClass('active');
            menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
            $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true,true).slideDown('normal');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp('normal');
        }

    });
});

</script>
```

Html and PHP:

```
<ul class="aside-menu">
<?php $parents = get_terms('product_category',array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>
<?php foreach($parents as $parent): ?>

    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $parent->name; ?></a>
        <ul>
        <?php $children = get_terms('product_category',array('parent' => $parent->term_id, 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
        <?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->slug,'product_category'); ?>"><?php echo $child->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I know how to get the current page by php (wordpress)

```
<?php echo get_queried_object()->parent == $parent->term_id ? '' : '' ?>
```

Know what should i do in order to tell javascript to open the  section of the menu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I _very_ strongly disagree with the first statement.  Javascript's awesome, man!

Comment: couldn't you use a wordpress menu and then use the built in css classes to select the currently opened menu? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will:

```
<?php if(get_queried_object()->parent == $parent->term_id): ?>
<script>
 yourJavaScriptFunction(<?php echo $parent->term_id; ?>);
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Update: In some place of your file...

```
<script>
function yourJavaScriptFunction(data) {
 alert("This data is from Ajax: " + data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to call a Javascript function after I'm getting the page id by php, what I don't know how to do it's the 'yourJavaScriptFunction()' function itself.

I think i should use "jquery event trigger" but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: sorry i didn't got your answer.